# AS3 using addChild() with a variable taken from a XML

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a function that would add a child from my library using a variable made from an xml.

```
var ChosenGraphic:String = units.unit.(@titel==k1).graphic;
var mc:MovieClip = new ChosenGraphic;
addChild(mc);
```

I know I can't use :String for this, but I don't have a clue what to use. I'm trying to get it to work for 2 hours now, and it's getting really frustrating.
Everything else works, I've tested that.

Comment: Is the string the class name of the MovieClip you're trying to instantiate? If not, what is the string representing?

Comment: Yes it is, I don't know what to put there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [getDefinitionByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29) top level function.

Below is an example of using it, lifted straight from the documentation that I linked to. Note that the class name string must be the fully qualified class name (ie: it includes the package name as well as the class).

```
package {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    public class GetDefinitionByNameExample extends Sprite {
        private var bgColor:uint = 0xFFCC00;
        private var size:uint = 80;

        public function GetDefinitionByNameExample() {
            var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("flash.display.Sprite") as Class;
            var instance:Object = new ClassReference();
            instance.graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
            instance.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
            instance.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(DisplayObject(instance));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, Didn't think I had to go through all this hassle to do this. But I still have a problem with this, I'm probably doing something wrong.
`var k2:String = units.unit.(@titel==k1).graphic;


 var kClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(k2) as Class;

 var tempadd:MovieClip = new kClass() ;

 addChild(tempadd);
`
This gives me back: Error #1065: Variable is not defined

Comment: Nvm, I got it working, something was wrong with the MC I was calling. Thank you very much!